# How to round to reasonable value java

Tags: java, rounding

Do anyone know how to round off to "reasonable" values in Java? For example, I want the program to round 1.7999999999999998 off to 1.8, 2.749999999999997 to 2.75, and so on. It depends on how many decimal places that are significant (not whole lists of 9s), but if I, for instance, just say that it cuts off after 5 9s, then if the number is 99999.1111111111111111, then I do not want it to round off to 10000, and the equivalent in the decimal digits 0.99999299999999994 to round off to 0.999993 instead of 1.

Comment: How many decimal places do you want to round to?

Comment: @hev1 it depends on reasonableness: sometimes I want 2, sometimes 1, sometimes 5

Comment: What is your exact criteria for rounding then?

Comment: I just would like "fuzzy logic"

Comment: If I use printf, it gives me a whole bunch of 0s, which I also don't want.

Comment: That makes it hard to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219373/discussion-between-3b1b-supporter-and-hev1).